# How can I modify this code, which rotates a CGImage, not to crop the image on rotate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

This function rotates a CGImage by an arbitrary number of degrees, but it clips the image a bit. How can I avoid the clipping?

Making the rectangle a bit larger seems to distort the image being rotated.

```
+ (CGImageRef)CGImageRotatedByAngle:(CGImageRef)imgRef angle:(CGFloat)angle {

  float angleInRadians = angle * (M_PI / 180);
  float width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
  float height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

  CGRect imgRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
  CGRect rotatedRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(imgRect, transform);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                 rotatedRect.size.width,
                                                 rotatedRect.size.height,
                                                 8,
                                                 0,
                                                 colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(bmContext,
                        +(rotatedRect.size.width/2),
                        +(rotatedRect.size.height/2));
  CGContextRotateCTM(bmContext, angleInRadians);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(bmContext,
                        -(rotatedRect.size.width/2),
                        -(rotatedRect.size.height/2));
  CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                           rotatedRect.size.width,
                                           rotatedRect.size.height),
                                           imgRef);

  CGImageRef rotatedImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);
  CFRelease(bmContext);
  [(id)rotatedImage autorelease];

  return rotatedImage;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm trying to use the same piece of code and haven't figured out how to fix it so the image does not get cropped. Did you ever find a good solution for this? Thanks !!

Comment: I think maybe I padded the image in question with a transparent border, and hacked it that way. Looking back, I'm not sure why I marked this answered.

Comment: It's been a while since this was posted, but see new answer--rotates without clipping and preserves original image's aspect ratio within bounding box.

Answer (score 1):

The code as written does not account for the difference in the sizes of the source and destination images.  You need to account for this before or when invoking CGContextDrawImage.  The code as written also does not preserve the original aspect ratio of the image -- it uses the destination size and height rather than the original.

The most succinct way to achieve the answer to the OP's question in the example code is to replace the line

```
    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, 
                       CGRectMake(0,
                                  0,
                                  rotatedRect.size.width
                                  rotatedRect.size.height), 
                       imgRef);
```

with

```
    CGContextDrawImage(bmContext, 
                       CGRectMake((rotatedRect.size.width-width)/2.,
                                  (rotatedRect.size.height-height)/2.,
                                  width,
                                  height), 
                       imgRef);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I had a similar though not identical problem.  I had a UIImage and a transform on that UIImage (transform was an accumulation of rotation and scale transforms from a UI with UIImageView and Gestures and I then needed to take the image and combine in with a background to make a single image so instead of a rotation I had the accumulated transform) and I had it mostly working but the rotation part was not correct and this clued me in. Thanks!   However, I am not sure why this works exactly.  Your line plus the TranslateCTM transforms on both side of my transform.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully get this.  These geometry questions are très très difficile.

But just looking at the geometry I would try:

- Round the rotated width and height up to nearest pixel.
- Don't do the second translate.
- Check the sign of the first translate and the first and second angle rotation.
- Plot the image at rectangle (-width/2, -height/2, width, height).

Comment: Both translations necessary to offset center of translation and then invert it; first rotation is used only to get the size of the new bounding rectangle.  The fourth bullet point is close, but see my post for the correct answer.

Comment: Oops my bad--omitting second translate and using fourth bullet is equivalent to my solution--I'll reverse downvote when possible